# How to install Node.js in PCBSD 10.3 - 11.0

Tags: node.js, pc-bsd

I'm trying to install Node.js in PC-BSD but the directory `/usr/ports` seems to be empty

Using [the instructions in this link](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager), I tried:

```
pkg install node
```

But I get this error:

[image]

Is there a working way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you must specify node.js’ category.

I haven't used FreeBSD in a while, but I think it's under 'www' or 'lang'. You would have to do:

```
pkg install www/node
```

or

```
pkg install lang/node
```

If you want, you can bookmark [this FreeBSD page](https://www.freshports.org/).